# Is there any event that fire for PowerPoint animations at start and end?

Tags: vba, vsto, powerpoint

We're developing a PowerPoint plugin, recently we got a requirement from our client to start certain functionality after animation on an object is completed but I'm not able to find any animation finished or started events.

Comment: Here's a [list of PowerPoint events](http://www.officeoneonline.com/vba/events_version.html), but I don't see any that deal with animations.

Answer (score 0):

As PeterT has mentioned, there are no events fired when shapes animate.  But here's a possible workaround. It may or may not fit your needs:

Add a shape the size of the animated shape, give it a Run Macro Action Setting *on mouse-over* (not on click).  Have it run whatever macro you've written to do what's needed.

Make the shape 99% transparent and animate it to appear automatically after the main shape you've animated.

Result: your original shape animates on, then the (for all intents) invisible add'l shape appears and as soon as the user wiggles the mouse, the macro fires.

If you can't be sure that the user will have the mouse over the shapes in question, try adding a full-slide shape instead to trigger the macro. In that case, to avoid having the macro trigger repeatedly, you might need to have the macro make the shape that triggers it invisible or have the macro remove the action setting or the like.